# Flash CS5 generates unwanted preloader

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader

One of our external developers has created a minigame in Flash CS5 which we are embedding in our container by loading the SWF. The minigame's document class (`Icegame`) should and does implement a specific interface `DreambearMinigame`.

However, it appears that when that game is published some kind of preloader is generated, since when loading the game in the container and casting `loader.content` to `DreambearMinigame` we get the error `cannot convert Icegame__Preloader__@blabla to DreambearMinigame`

We've rummaged through the publish settings of the minigame's FLA but can't find the place to turn this off. What's going on?

Comment: Found it: http://www.stevensacks.net/2010/05/28/flash-cs5-tlf-engine-causes-errors-with-loaded-swfs/ - Maybe I'll write it as a decent answer later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved since July 1st by asker, with no accepted answer. Therefore, to drop this to the bottom of unanswered (and maybe even remove it from that tab if this gets accepted...) I'm posting a rote answer as a community courtesy.

**Here is the link posted above, that the asker said answered the question: [Flash CS5 TLF Engine Causes Errors with Loaded SWFs](http://www.stevensacks.net/2010/05/28/flash-cs5-tlf-engine-causes-errors-with-loaded-swfs/).**

If anyone can offer a better (read more detailed) answer, please feel free to do so. I can't answer this well because I don't have the expertise to do so. Again, this is just a community service...a bit of a habit of mine.

Comment: To elaborate, the specific tip used from the linked page is "UPDATE 2
If you go into the Actionscript settings of the swf using the TLF Engine and changed the Runtime Shared Library Settings Default linkage to "Merged into code" the errors go away."